# Fading table cells with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found this code, it supposed to find the first cell in the visible row and when I click it the cell is supposed to fadeout or fadein.

I want to adjust the code so that an input button will make this, How can I do this?

```
$('tr:visible').find('td:first').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean that the function should be executed when you click a specific button.

```
button.click(function () {
    $('tr:visible').find('td:first').parent().next().fadeToggle()
}
```

Where 'button' is a variable with a reference to the button you wish to perform the fade.

Comment: You could simplify the inner line to: `$('tr:visible td:first').parent().next().fadeToggle()`. Better yet, why go to the td and then `.parent()`, and not just stay in the tr? So, we could simplify it further: `$('tr:visible').next().fadeToggle()`

Comment: Also, remember to put a `;` at the end of the line.